# Python tkinter import error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, import

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root= Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Error:

> ...Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Lee\Desktop\Python projects\tkinter.py", line 1, in 
>       import tkinter  as Tk   File "C:\Users\Lee\Desktop\Python projects\tkinter.py", line 2, in 
>       from tkinter import messagebox ImportError: cannot import name 'messagebox'

[Finished in 25.248s] I have no idea why messagebox won't import?

Answer (score 5):

You named your file `tkinter.py`, so when you import `tkinter`, it's importing that file rather than the real tkinter module.

Rename your file to just about anything else.