# Module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter doesnt contain any tk attribute.

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

win.mainloop()
```

While running this code it gives me an error saying

```
module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'tk'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480367/attributeerror-module-tkinter-has-no-attribute-tk)

Comment: Did you name your file "tkinter.py"? This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46477882/7432

Answer (score 53):

Did you named your python file tkinter.py or Tkinter.py ? Try to rename it. It may be the cause.

if the file  name is tkinter.py in program

import tkinter

it will imports the our file name which is overriders the content there is not Tk() module, so it throw the error

Comment: Thank u so much.My problem is solved after renaming my Python file from "Tkinter.py" to any name you want.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great answer, that really would be the last thing I'd think of.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the error occurred in `top =tk.Tk()`
The simple trick I used was to change the uppercase K in 'TK' to lowercase k

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
top =tk.Tk()
top.geometry('800x600')
top.title('Image Processing')
top.configure(background='#CDCDCD')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3.x**

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter

raiz= tkinter.Tk()

raiz.mainloop()
```

remember that the file name cannot be tkinter.py

Comment: the code is useless but the hint with the filename is good. Please be clearer with your answers next time

Answer (score 0):

try `Tk` instead of `tk`
it worked for me, if you think you are importing wrong,try:

```
import tkinter
tkinter._test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the file to the Python path in C drive (in my case)

And the folder should not contain any other file named Tkinter.py or similar [for Code click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3h2G.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

it's capital 'T' and small 'k' =>> 'Tk' not capital K make sure, small mistake

Comment: How is this different from other answers here?

Answer (score 0):

Your python script name is must not be tkinker.py python could prioritize your script as tkinker and that couldn return that error.